# SQL script doesnt work but individual queries work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the following script to add a column to my table. When I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> in the query window it gives an error on the 2nd update query that `fkRefTabNo` doesn't exist.

```
ALTER TABLE EPFieldSQLScripts
ADD fkRefTabNo int  DEFAULT 1

update EPFieldSQLScripts
set fkRefTabNo = 1
where fkRefTabNo is null

ALTER TABLE EPFieldSQLScripts
ALTER COLUMN fkRefTabNo INTEGER NOT NULL
```

But when I run these queries one by one, it doesn't give an error. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `GO` between statements. This way the result of each statement will be committed before running the next one (each statement will be a separate transaction).

```
ALTER TABLE EPFieldSQLScripts
ADD fkRefTabNo int  DEFAULT 1

GO

update EPFieldSQLScripts
set fkRefTabNo = 1
where fkRefTabNo is null

GO

ALTER TABLE EPFieldSQLScripts
ALTER COLUMN fkRefTabNo INTEGER NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, adding `GO` is the solution. It's not the *reason* though

SQL Server is trying to run your entire script as a single transaction, and then only committing the data to the database when the script completes. So at the point at which

```
update EPFieldSQLScripts
set fkRefTabNo = 1
where fkRefTabNo is null
```

is run (and queued ready for commit), the field `fkRefTabNo` has not actually been added to the database table (which only happens on commit). Adding the `GO` statements - or, running each statement individually - commits the transactions to the database before continuing with the next statement, hence why you're seeing a difference in behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `GO` in between each of these statements the outcome should be the same as executing each one seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Put ; at the end of each query statement

Like

```
ALTER TABLE EPFieldSQLScripts ADD fkRefTabNo int  DEFAULT 1;

update EPFieldSQLScripts set fkRefTabNo = 1 where fkRefTabNo is null;

ALTER TABLE EPFieldSQLScripts;

ALTER COLUMN fkRefTabNo INTEGER NOT NULL;
```

Now it must work together.

Comment: `;` is no requirement in `TSQL` only for some minor exceptions for example when using `WITH`