# Can't execute .SQL script but queries work individually

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL 5.5, I am able to execute the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` queries individually but when I put them in a `.sql` script I receive the following error twice:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

I tried to use the GO statement as recommended here ([SQL script doesnt work but individual queries work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316919/sql-script-doesnt-work-but-individual-queries-work)) but no luck.

Here's my now working script thanks to comments:

```
-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    age INTEGER
);

-- Populate the table
INSERT INTO person
(id, first_name, last_name, age)
VALUES
  (0, 'Zed', 'Shaw', 37),
  (1, 'Terry', 'Berry', 42),
  (2, 'Tyler', 'Brown', 25),
  (3, 'Frank', 'Smith', 100);
```

Thanks for your help!

Here's the complete error message:

```
mysql> SOURCE ~/code/Learn-SQL-The-Hard-Way/Exercise-12-Destroying-And-Altering-Tables/recreate-person-table.sql
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--Create the table
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_n' at line 1
ERROR: 
No query specified

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--Populate the table
INSERT INTO person
(id, first_name, last_name, age)
VALUES
' at line 1
```

Comment: That other question is for SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Uhm, `GO` is not for MySQL, isn't that something for MSSQL?

Comment: What is the complete error message you get?

Comment: If that's MySQL, remove GO :)

Comment: After removing GO, I still received the same error messages.

Comment: My guess is you're not using ASCII hyphens in your comments. What happens if you remove the comment lines?

Comment: @Barmar I'm still getting the same errors

Comment: How can you get the same errors when the lines in the error messages have been removed?

Comment: @Barmar my mistake you're right. I had additional comments at the top of the script that I didn't include but were still running. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `--` syntax for mysql comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html) includes a space.  `--word` is not a comment, but `-- word` is.  The space is important.

I can't find any documentation for `GO`, but based on our error messages it actually works.  You don't need it though.  A semicolon, `;`, does the same.